# Pasar Array PHP a objeto JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, array, chart.js

Tengo el siguiente array en PHP:

```
$fechas = array(2) {
    [0]=> string(30) "Miércoles 13 de Enero de 2021"
    [1]=> string(26) "Jueves 14 de Enero de 2021"
}
```

Y el siguiente objeto en JavaScript:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    }
});
```

Como se darán cuenta estoy usando chart.js

Lo que encesito es que el array de PHP se muestre en data.labels

De esta manera:

```
labels: ['Miércoles 13 de Enero de 2021', 'Jueves 14 de Enero de 2021']
```

He intentado hacer esto:

```
var dates = '<?php echo json_encode($fechas); ?>';
labels: dates
```

Per me devuelve este error en la consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.ticks.map is not a function

Agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he resuelto, como lo estaba haciendo estaba bien, pero primero se debe convertir a objeto JavaScript, de esta forma:

PHP:

```
$fechas = array(2) {
    [0]=> string(30) "Miércoles 13 de Enero de 2021"
    [1]=> string(26) "Jueves 14 de Enero de 2021"
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var dates = '<?php echo json_encode($fechas); ?>';

data: {
    labels: JSON.parse(dates) // Aquí se hace la conversión
}
```